# Run a Gluster service into a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, service, containers, glusterfs

The issue is make a Gluster service work into a docker container (i tried with Fedora and Ubuntu images). The main problem reside in the process when I have to run the command: `service glusterd start` [code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbNTr.png), after the instalation of Gluster (`yum install glusterfs-server` command in the case of Fedora) none file appears in `/etc/init.d/glusterd` where "service" command make it calls.

Are there any way of make a Gluster containerized without make a Docker Swarm?

[My gluster version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nw6i.png)

This is my /etc folder in Fedora [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hyZi.png)

This is my /etc/init.d folder in Ubuntu [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEaB0.png)

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: That's still not programming.